# URL Error posting image to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, url, bitmap

I want to send a image taken by the user to a Facebook share dialog post. 
The image taken from device camera h is set to a imageview and also saved to the device external storage/ SD card.

The facebook share SDK takes a URL for a image in the .setPicture(URL) method.

So my question is it possible to get the URL of a image from either the bitmap in the imageview or the image stored in the deice?

Or is the URL specifically for a network resource?
Cheers
ciaran

EDIT: Have tried adding the path to sd card/external storage of device as a string to the

```
setLink(URL string) method:
setLink("/storage/emulated/0/dive_photos/image2462.png")
```

but image does not load, exceptions thrown in Logcat is ....

> 03-02 00:06:04.280: E/Activity(3055): Error:
>   com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message Share preview
>   could not be fetched
>
> (#100)picture url not properly formed

Treied removing the first "/" by getting substring(1) and passing `setLink("storage/emulated/0/dive_photos/image2462.png")`
but same error....

Although a network resource url works fine:

```
setLink("http://www.mooneycallans.com/images/Gallery/image51.jpg")
```

EDIT:
Also tried creating a file://imagePathString URL some progress made, the share preview will show the image however will still not post get the same (#100)  Pictire URL not properly formed....

```
    File imagePathFile = new File(savedImagePath);

                        try{
                         userImageURL = imagePathFile.toURI().toURL();


                        Log.d(TAG, "File URL for saved image on FB: " + userImageURL);
                        }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
                            //ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         userImageURLString = userImageURL.toString();

        setPicture(userImageURLString)

//userImageURLString = "file:/storage/emulated/0/dive_photos/image4373.png";
```

My head is wrecked:(

Comment: You say that you save the file to the sdcard, how would you go about doing that if you do not know the file path? Hence your question answers itself.

Comment: yep tried passing the path as a string to the Facebook setPicture(url) method but image doesn't not display nor the post, no exceptions thrown in Logcat, this is the same as passing null (setLink(null)...haven't had many responses to this question wonder if it needs to be rephrased..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much seraching a very confusing FB documentation I found the method

```
 setPicture(URL string)
```

will only accept a network resource URL.
To upload a photo form app need the Request class:

```
Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, imagePathFile, uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
```